# Exception in Magento 1.5.0.1

Tags: php, magento

I get an error message in the bottom of the page :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message
>   'Serialization of 'Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element' is not allowed' in
>   [no active file]:0 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in [no active file]
>   on line 0

Problem is i don't get any file or line number. 
Have you seen this before? Where can I start to fix it?

I searched on google and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422876/serialization-not-allowed-in-magento) answer but the response is not valid in my case. Didn't find any other response, probably because of large number of websites that display this error.

Comment: Try disable full page cache, blocks HTML output cache and layouts cache and see, did error disappear.

Comment: Caching is completely disabled

Comment: Does this error happen while unit testing?

Comment: Are you sure full page cache is disabled? It is configured in another place then all other ones.

Comment: How can i check if full page caching is disabled or not?

Answer (score 0):

http://magentophp.blogspot.com/2011/02/magento-enterprise-full-page-caching.html

This might clarify the Magento Full caching

Regards Bernd